# R How to use file.exist with an object connection

Tags: r, file

In R, I have an object of type connection and would prefer to use directly the connection instead of the initial path to check if the file exists:

```
file.exist("path")
```

Is there any method to get the path from the connection, apparently it is not in the attributes, but I can still see the path when printing the connection in the console...

Comment: the cleanest way to get the path of a file-connection I found was: `x <- file(tempfile());
summary(x)$description`

Comment: Thank I completely forgot I could use summary on that; it is working great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from @Stefan F comment is working perfectly :

```
path <- summary(my_connection)$description
```